# How to make a REST API POST (to Excel) in Node js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, post, promise

I am new to Node.js, and I am struggling to make a POST in a REST API architecture in Node.js. The post is supposed to write new tasks in an Excel file. I figured out how to write the tasks in an Excel worksheet, but I cannot make the POST through the REST API. The following examples will clarify:

This is how I write a new task in an Excel worksheet and it works!:

```
const xlsx = require('xlsx');

//read the Excel file
workBook = xlsx.readFile("todo-list.xlsx", {cellDates:true});


// Add a new worksheet to the existing file
const headerArray = ["Completed", "Id", "Task Name", "Description", "Due Date", "Priority", "Status", "Notes"]; //the header of the table
const firstTaskArray = ["No", 1, "Soup", "broccoli, carrots, onion, and blend",
    new Date(2021,12, 12), "Low", "Not Started", "Search for a tutorial"]; // the new task that has to be added
const cookingListData = [headerArray, firstTaskArray]; // the list that has to be added

// Add array of array (the cooking list data) to the cooking list
const cookingList = xlsx.utils.aoa_to_sheet(cookingListData);


// Add the newly created sheet to the workbook
xlsx.utils.book_append_sheet(workBook, cookingList, "Do-Cooking");
```

And this is my hello.js file from the 'components' folder. I think **HERE IS THE PROBLEM**! Within the Promise, because I do not know how to repair it/make it work.

```
"use strict";

const request = require('request')
const xlsx = require('xlsx');


const Hello = {
    postHello: () => {
        return new Promise (((resolve, reject) => {
            let workBook = xlsx.readFile("todo-list.xlsx", {cellDates:true});
            
            const cookingListData = [headerArray, firstTaskArray];

            // ADD array of array (the cooking list data) to the cooking list
            const cookingList = xlsx.utils.aoa_to_sheet(cookingListData);

            // ADD the newly created sheet to the workbook
            xlsx.utils.book_append_sheet(workBook, cookingList, "Do-Cooking");
            return resolve(cookingList);
        }))
    }
};

module.exports = Hello
```

And this is how my hello.js from the api folder looks like:

```
const HelloRouter = require('express').Router();

const Hello = require('./../components/hello');

HelloRouter.post('/welcome', (req, res) => {
    Hello.postHello().then(message => {
        return res.json(message);
    }).catch((error) => {
        return res.json(404, error);
    });
});
module.exports = HelloRouter;
```

Can you help me please? I honestly don't know how to make it work:( Let me know if I have to add further information.

**EDIT**:

I think the problem is within the Promise, as the server successfully started, but I cannot make the post. I tried to make this in Postman and it gives me an error:
[image]

Comment: Could you defined what is not working exaclty ? Do you have any errors, What is happening that should not, what is not happening that should ?

Comment: Yes! The post itself is not working, I think the problem is within the Promise, which is in the hello.js from the component folder. The server started successfully, so it is not a problem with the program/server itself, I think I just don't know to repair the Promise.:( I edited the post with a test on Postman. @Nicolas

Comment: Why are you returning a resolve? You don't return resolves. Just resolve() and return. Try removing the return.

Answer (score 0):

in your main **app.js** or **server.js**

use `app.use(HelloRouter)` in order to expose that post request.

Comment: thank you, but I already have it.  I think the problem is within the Promise..

Comment: Edit your post with the code you start the server with.

Answer (score 0):

```
HelloRouter
   .route('/welcome')
   .post(async (req, res, next) => {
        await Hello.postHello();
            return res.json('whatever the message is');
        }).catch((error) => {
            return res.status(404).send(error);
        });
    });
```

Can you try this ? would be nice to exactly know whats happening after you send a request. do you not get a response or do you get an error as a response, and if so what error